Why ctypes.CDLL is assuming long result type even though it's actually is long long?
Consider python code below - it seems that calling .dll's function is assuming long time for some reason (system is windows x64 if it's important).
Why it's doing this? Is there way to disable it? Will it get in the way in other cases, e.g. if I'm going to pass long long arguments or initialize structs using long longs?
import ctypes

hello_lib = ctypes.CDLL("./hello.dll")

n = 13
# returns 1932053504 instead of 6227020800
print(hello_lib.factorial(n))

# for some reason result type is long,
# though it's declared as long long in .dll
# <class 'ctypes.c_long'>
print(hello_lib.factorial.restype)

hello_lib.factorial.restype = ctypes.c_longlong
# return 6227020800, changing result type helped
print(hello_lib.factorial(n))


.dll code:
// choco install mingw
// gcc -shared -o hello.dll hello.c

#include <stdio.h>

long long int factorial(int n) {
    if (n>=1) {
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
    return 1;
}



[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer),

ctypes has no idea what the return type is.  DLLs only provide the names and entry points of C functions, not argument or return types.  c_int (aliased to c_long on OSes where they are the same size) is just the default.
It is the user's responsibility to set .argtypes and .restype accordingly based on the function's C prototype.
For example, a C function prototype of:
double sum(double a, double b);

would require the following:
lib = ctypes.CDLL(<path>)
lib.sum.argtypes = ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double
lib.sum.restype = ctypes.c_double


If this information is not present in dll then .dll itself seems not useful without corresponding .h. But what about symbols than can be included to .dll or they are more just an information and no one relies on them? Also, does it mean that all programs that use some .dll are either using it's .h as they access .dll or were already compiled using it's .h?

@FamousSnake That's why a C compiler needs the header.  Languages that interop with C need the header information as well.  Programs can also dynamically load DLLs like Python but the programmer still needs to know the declarations of the functions to access them correctly.

@FamousSnake In regards to "symbols" a DLL exports the names of global variables as well so those can be accessed via ctypes.in_dll, e.g. ctypes.c_double.in_dll(lib, 'pi') for a double pi = 3.1415; C global.  The type still needs to be known.
